# REST API - SOAPUI - POST script generates key ID at the end of the query

Tags: api, rest, soapui

I have a bit of a problem here. I was making some API tests using the POST Method in SOAP UI. I put this script to generate a new entry

```
{
   "title":"Mark",
   "author":"Hampton",
   "text":"TestRest",
   "created":"${#Project#Timestamp}" - can be a fixed value
}
```

I got a proper response and an entry is created as following

```
{
   "title":"Mark",
   "author":"Hampton",
   "text":"TestRest",
   "created":"12/05/2022-15:40",
   "id":6
}
```

The "id" property is generated automatically. I was wondering if there is a way to force the "id" property to be on top. When I did a PATCH method and added a new parameter. The "id" property was above the new parameter

```
{
   "title":"Johan",
   "author":"Dudes",
   "text":"Dyke",
   "created":"12/05/2022-15:40",
   "id":6,
   "updated":"12/06/2022-17:07"
}
```

So, how can I do a POST method where the ID is generated automatically at the top, and in the response script, the ID parameter is not at the bottom of a response

Comment: Why is the order important for you? A JSON object is an unordered map (dictionary) of key-value pairs.

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)